# How to loop over templates in silverstripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

**Hello**,

I'm doing a one-page site in silverstripe and i have created some templates that will represent my different site parts.

I first tried to loop by using 'include' so :

```
<% if SlugItems %>
    <% loop SlugItems %>
        <% include $slug %>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```

But from what i found on forums, it's not the way to do it and i got an error with loop tag missing...So i tried to create a function

```
public function IncludeTemplate($template) {
    return $this->renderWith($template);
}
```

And

```
<% if SlugItems %>
    <% loop SlugItems %>
        <% IncludeTemplate($Slug) %>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```

Big surprise...It's the same, cause i read that both include and renderWith do the same job.
Well, i don't really know a good solution and i'd like to implement something more elaborate than including some template if my template name is like X, eg.

```
<% if $ClassName = 'SomeClass' %>
    <% include SomeClass %> 
<% else_if $ClassName = 'SomeOtherClass' %>
    <% include SomeOtherClass %>
<% else %>
    <% include DefaultClass %>
<% end_if %>
```

If you know a good solution, please write it here! That would make my day :D.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it sounds like you are trying to do is similar to a module called [Content Blocks](https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks/).

In that module, they have an identical situation where they loop over blocks and insert the right template for that block.

The module's [`Page.ss`](https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks/blob/master/templates/Layout/Page.ss):

```
<% loop $ActiveBlocks %>$Me<% end_loop %>
```

`$ActiveBlocks` refers to a [function on a DataExtension by the same name](https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks/blob/master/code/ContentBlocksModule.php#L59).

This is all stuff that you are already familiar with. The part that you might not know so much about is the `$Me` value in the template. [It can be used to refer to the current object context the template is rendered with](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates#looping-over-lists), in your case that would be a `Slug`.

That is only part of the magic, the other part is a function on the `Block` DataObject the called [`forTemplate`](https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks/blob/master/code/dataobjects/Block.php#L245). This is called when using `$Me` to work out how to render the DataObject.

In here, you can just perform a classic `renderWith` call like this:

```
return $this->renderWith(array($this->Template, 'Slug'));
```

With this knowledge, you could achieve what you are after by having a `Slug` DataObject looking something like this:

```
class Slug extends DataObject
{
    static $db = array();

    function getTemplate()
    {
        $template = 'yourTemplate';

        //Do your template logic checks in here to work out what you want to display

        return $template;
    }

    function forTemplate()
    {
        return $this->renderWith(array($this->Template, 'Slug'));
    }
}
```

With your template looking something like this:

```
<% if $Slugs %>
    <% loop $Slugs %>
        $Me
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```

Answer (score 2):

i did something similar in my [onepage module](https://github.com/wernerkrauss/silverstripe-onepage/)

try something like that:

```
    /**
    * renders the current page using the ClassName_onepage template,
    * e.g. Page_onepage
    *
    * @return HTMLText
    */
    public function getOnePageContent(){
    $templateName = SSViewer::get_templates_by_class($this->owner->Classname, '_onepage', 'SiteTree')
    ?: 'Page_onepage';
    return $this->renderWith($templateName);
    }
```

And in your template:

```
    <% if SlugItems %>
        <% loop SlugItems %>
            $OnePageContent
        <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
```

HTH,

wmk

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's a good one but the first one is cleaner i think

Answer (score 0):

You can define a template file, say Slug.ss, where you put the HTML you want to loop over, and save it into themes/your-theme/templates/Includes.

Then you can just loop over it with this code:

```
<% if SlugItems %>
    <% loop SlugItems %>
        <% include Slug %>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```